# How can I use Ember Data's FixtureAdapter with real API content

Tags: ember-data, fixtures

I want to populate my Ember Data fixtures with real content taken from an API data dump instead of the standard fixtures. I don't want to use the API directly.

I want to do this so I can imitate a local instance of the API data.

How can I streamline this and also how might I configure the adapter to allow this?

Consider this default FIXTURE:

```
App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    article: DS.belongsTo('article'),
    author: DS.belongsTo('user'),
    dateCreated: DS.attr('date', {readOnly: true}),
    dateModified: DS.attr('date', {readOnly: true}),
    description: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Comment.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    temp: 1,
    author: 1,
    dateCreated: 'Mon Jul 28 2014 12:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)',
    dateModified: null,
    description: 'lorem ipsum'
}];
```

Consider this API response:

```
{"comments": [
  {
    "articleID": 1,
    "description": "I am a comment",
    "authorID": 1,
    "dateCreated": "2014-09-04T02:39:00",
    "createdBy": "Elise Chant",
    "dateModified": "2014-09-04T02:39:00",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "articleID": 1,
    "description": "I am another comment",
    "authorID": 1,
    "dateCreated": "2014-09-04T02:48:00",
    "createdBy": "Elise Chant",
    "dateModified": "2014-09-04T02:48:00",
    "id": 2
  }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get your backend to provide a data dump method from the API with the resources, such as:

```
http://myapi/dump
```

The method shall return a zipped folder of files representing the site's resources, such as `Comment.js`, `User.js`, `Article.js`.

Each of these files should return the JSON resource wrapped by DS.Model.FIXTURES array, such as

```
App.Comment.FIXTURES = 
[
  {
    "articleID": 1,
    "userID": 1,
    "description": "I am a comment.",
    "category": 0,
    "authorID": 1,
    "dateCreated": "2014-09-04T02:39:00",
    "id": 1
  },
  // ...
];
```

Remember to make sure that each `.js` file is an included script tag in html and appears after its corresponding model. Check this is available in the Browser's Developer Console.

Finally, In order to correctly connect asynchronous relationships such as `articleID` and `authorID`, property names need to be normalised like that would be if you were using normal fixture data. So configure the adapter to strip 'ID' from the end of any belongsTo relationships by parsing the FIXTURES payload:

```
if (App.ENV === 'DEV') {

    App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.JSONSerializer.extend({

        // access to the payload
        extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
            var self = this;
            return payload.map(function(item) {
                // normalise incoming data
                return self.normalize(type, item);
            });
        },

        normalize: function(type, hash) {
            if (!hash) { return hash; }

            var normalizedHash = {},
                normalizedProp;

            for (var prop in hash) {
                if (!!prop.match(/ID$/)) {
                    // belongs to / has Many attribute
                    // remove 'ID' from the end of the property name
                    normalizedProp = prop.substr(0, prop.length-2);
                } else {   // regular attribute
                    normalizedProp = prop;
                }

                normalizedHash[normalizedProp] = hash[prop];
            }

            this.normalizeId(normalizedHash);
            this.normalizeUsingDeclaredMapping(type, normalizedHash);
            this.applyTransforms(type, normalizedHash);
            return normalizedHash;
        }
    });

    App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
        simulateRemoteResponse: true,
        latency: 1000,
        // This "unsets" serializer so that the store will lookup the proper serializer
        // @see https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1333
        serializer: function() {
            return;
        }.property()
    });

} else {

    DS.CustomRESTSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
        keyForRelationship: function(key, kind) {
            if (kind === 'belongsTo') {
                return key + 'ID';
            } else {
                return key;
            }
        }
    });

    App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        host: App.HOST,
        namespace: App.NAMESPACE,
        ajax: function(url, method, hash) {
            hash = hash || {}; // hash may be undefined
            hash.crossDomain = true;
            hash.xhrFields = {withCredentials: true};
            return this._super(url, method, hash);
        },
        defaultSerializer: 'DS/customREST'
    });

}
```